# How to distinguish actor termination reason

Tags: akka.net

I mean I did everything as described in docs:

```
Receive<InitTopicMessage>(m =>
{
  parserActor = getParserActor(Context, rootTopicId);
  Context.Watch(parserActor);
}

// ...

Receive<Terminated>(t =>
{
   if(t == parserActor)
   {
       // do some stuff
   }
}
```

The problem is that I want to *do some stuff* only if parser actor was terminated because of error, and not because of ActorSystem termination.

So, is there any way to distinguish the reason of the actor termination?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will receive a termination message for one of two reasons:

1. The remote actor was terminated gracefully
2. The remote process crashed or there was a network failure.

You can distinquish between the two with `Terminated.AddressTerminated`

If `Terminated.AddressTerminated == true` then it was a crash or network failure.

If you need to to be more precise or handle certain errors then you'll want to use a [supervisor strategy](http://getakka.net/docs/Supervision) on the remote system (which could send the appropriate messages).

Akka is all about fault tolerance and resiliency though so you might be asking the wrong question. If the remote actor goes down, how do you make it recover without the parseActor even caring?

Comment: Thanks a lot! AddressTerminated is what I looked for

Answer (score 0):

There is another way to solve my problem, just in case if someone interested. I send custom message, indicating system shutdown, before terminating `ActorSystem`, and then actor just change its behavior to ignore `Terminated` message:

```cs
public class SomeActor : ReceiveActor
{
    public SomeActor()
    {
        Become(Working);
    }

    private void Working()
    {
        Receive<ApplicationStopMessage>(m =>
        {
            Become(ShuttingDown);
        });

        Receive<Terminated>(t =>
        {
            // do stuff on 
        });
    }

    private void ShuttingDown()
    {
        ReceiveAny(m =>
        {
            // ignore all messages
        });
    }
}

// somewhere in code
someActor.Tell(new ApplicationStopMessage());
actorSystem.Terminate();
```

now we will handle `Terminated` message only if it was send by failed child.

Not so obvious and clear as using `Terminated.AddressTerminated`, but worked for me